# Wordpress: Build array of ids from wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to capture all the id's available in the wp_query after a loop runs and place them into an array. I will use these ID's for a later function.

I tried this, but is there a better way?

```
        $temp = array();
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        $temp[] = $wp_query->post->ID ;
    endwhile;
    print_r($temp);
```

and get this:

Array ( [0] => 7050 [1] => 8227 [2] => 8206 [3] => 8202 [4] => 8200 [5] => 8190 [6] => 8180 [7] => 8174 [8] => 8172 [9] => 8168 [10] => 8162 [11] => 8150 [12] => 8144 [13] => 8138 [14] => 8132 [15] => 8134 [16] => 8130 [17] => 8126 [18] => 8128 [19] => 8124 )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
get_the_ID()
```

inseted of

```
the_ID() ;
```

try this

```
$temp = array();
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    $temp[] = get_the_ID() ;
endwhile;

print_r($temp);
```